# How upgrade SQL Server services?

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 Express Edition (64bit).

I have upgrade my Express edition to SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition.

At first I used "SQL Server Installation Center" and run "Upgrade from SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012".
All procedures for upgrade is fine.

Later I run Maintenance-Edition Upgrade in order to upgrade my edition wit Express to Standard Edition.

All procedures for upgrade are fine, SSMS view - SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) Standard Edition (64 bit), but SQL Server Services in SQL Server Configuration Manager is old (example - SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)). Why is the SQL Server service not updated? What have I done wrong?

Comment: When you install express, it's installed as a *named instance*, called `SQLEXPRESS`. If you then upgrade that instance, it retains its name.

Comment: Ok,but SQL Agent Services doesn't work. SQL Agent Services does not start.

Comment: Agent Service launch on  "System Local" account, thanks for help.